# How to mark deprecated fields in Django 1.4?

Tags: python, django, django-models, deprecated

What is the best way to mark deprecated fields in Django 1.4 models if I don't want to delete them right away?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve by marking them deprecated? Who would be the recipient of this information?

Comment: For other developers, @LudwikTrammer. They shouldn't use them in a feature!

Comment: Have you looked into the system check framework: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/checks/#field-model-and-manager-checks ?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I can't comment yet.

If you don't want anything fancy you could simply compare the Python version and launch a warning.

```
import django
print django.VERSION
>> (1, 8, 5, 'final', 0)
if django.VERSION[1] < 4:
    print "[DEPRECATION WARNING]"
```

Or you could do the best approach: to go to a popular package and see how they do it. For example in Django CMS:

`cms/exceptions.py` (https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/exceptions.py)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Deprecated(Exception): pass
```

`cms/utils/check.py` (https://github.com/divio/django-cms/blob/develop/cms/utils/check.py)

```
@define_check
def check_deprecated_settings(output):
    with output.section("Deprecated settings") as section:
        found = False
        for deprecated in ['CMS_FLAT_URLS', 'CMS_MODERATOR']:
            if hasattr(settings, deprecated):
                section.warn("Deprecated setting %s found. This setting is no longer in use and can be removed" % deprecated)
                found = True
        if not found:
            section.skip("No deprecated settings found")
```